Jetpack Compose Canvas - drawForPersistence invoked on a null object reference
Crashlytics is reporting a strange error, seemingly app is never crashing during the development. I wasn't able to find any occurrences of this (exact) error online. We do have a Composable that draws the arc with some data fetched from the view model. None of the data is null, all have default values so that's why I think null error isn't related to that. One recorded instance of this error happened when user downgraded the location permission from All the time to While in use (even tho app was killed with that action by the system).
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void androidx.compose.ui.graphics.layer.GraphicsLayer.drawForPersistence$ui_graphics_release(androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Canvas)' on a null object reference

at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.layer.LayerManager.persistLayers(LayerManager.android.kt:116)

at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.layer.LayerManager.updateLayerPersistence(LayerManager.android.kt:136)

at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.AndroidGraphicsContext$componentCallback$1$onTrimMemory$1.onPreDraw(AndroidGraphicsContext.android.kt:79)

at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:1204)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:4739)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:3302)

at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:11362)

at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1689)

at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1698)

at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1153)

at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1079)

at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1646)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:958)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)

at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:230)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:319)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8919)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:578)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1103) 

Here is Composable using the Canvas:
@Composable
private fun DrawArc(
    progress: ArcScoreConfig,
    progressColor: Color,
    strokeWidth: Dp,
    endCircleColor: Color = DesignTokenColor.colorSemanticDatavizIndicator,
    circularEnd: Boolean = false,
    animate: Boolean = true,
) {
    val target: MutableFloatState = rememberSaveable(progress.score) { 
mutableFloatStateOf
(0f) }
    //animation for the arc, arc is animated fairly simple
    //we draw arc using percentages of the float
    //so if the the score is 83 we multiply that we rising value
    //of our "target" (0-1), at all times arc (and circle) are just relatively
    //scaled down (by their angle). As the float value is rising, so is arc's end
    //angle/
    val animation: Float by animateFloatAsState(
        targetValue = target.floatValue,
        animationSpec = 
tween
(
            durationMillis = DiscountArcProgressConfig.animationDuration,
            delayMillis = DiscountArcProgressConfig.animationDelay,
            easing = 
LinearEasing
        
),
        label = "Arc animation"
    )

    LaunchedEffect(progress.score) {
        //trigger animation to start, must be triggered each time score changes
        //otherwise, arc won't be animated, only the end result will be drawn
        target.floatValue = progress.score.toFloat()
    }
    Column {
        Canvas(
            modifier = Modifier.
aspectRatio
(DiscountArcProgressConfig.aspectRatio)
        ) {
            val centerX = size.width / 2
            val centerY = size.height
            val path = 
Path
().
apply 
{
                arcTo(
                    rect = Rect(
                        centerX - centerY,
                        centerY - centerY,
                        centerX + centerY,
                        centerY + centerY
                    ),
                    startAngleDegrees = DiscountArcProgressConfig.startAngle,
                    //if animate flag is false, we just draw the arc with progress
                    //dashboard case would be 100, full half-circle
                    //if true, we use the animation
                    sweepAngleDegrees = DiscountArcProgressConfig.sweepAngle(
                        if (animate)
                            animation else progress.score.toFloat()
                    ),
                    forceMoveTo = false
                )
            }
            drawPath(
                path = path,
                color = progressColor,
                style = Stroke(
                    width = strokeWidth.
toPx
(),
                    cap = StrokeCap.Round
                )
            )
            if (circularEnd) {
                drawCircle(
                    color = endCircleColor,
                    radius = strokeWidth.
toPx
() / 2,
                    center = DiscountArcProgressConfig.circleOffset(
                        centerX,
                        centerY,
                        animation
                    )
                )
            }
        }
    }
}


I have also recently noticed this. It's in our Firebase Crashlytics and it is happening on prod. It always happens on App Open, and it is happening on Wear OS and on regular Android app (we are slowly moving to compose). Any idea?

Also, I have found this: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/344633768 tho no idea what release version this will be in.

@Ana looks like the issue was fixed in compose 1.7.0-beta04
Per comments on this issue: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/343750859
